# clear Arduino as a global variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use `Arduino` in `Matlab`. cause I used Arduino in some function I had to define `Arduino` as a global variable.

```
clc,clear,close all;
global a
a = arduino();
.
some functions
.
clear a
```

at the end of my code I `clear` the variable but as I run the code again this error appear:

```
Failed to open serial port (user COM) to communicate with board Uno. ...
 Make sure there is no other MATLAB arduino object for this board.
```

I guess the global function can't be clear by `clear` command so I tried `clear all` instead `clear` in the last line. It works perfect as I run it again and again but as you know this is `Matlab` tips for `clear all` command

```
Using clear all causes MATLAB® to recompile previously cached code, 
and can decrease performance.
```

I've tried `delete(a)` so the result was:

```
Error using arduino/delete
Cannot access method 'delete' in class 'arduino'.
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does contain the global variable `a = arduino();` ?

Comment: cause it's recall in all sub functions. like `writePWMDutyCycle(a,E1, 0);`

Comment: sub functions use local value by default and save in separated location in `matlab`. one way is use `a` as an input argument for all of function. but i'm looking for another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MatLab Help Center they had nice description of how to clear a variable from memory. Check it here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clearvars.html

In your case should be: `clearvars -global a;`